# Find $\sin(10^{\circ})$, if $\cos(40^{\circ}) = a$

Tags: trigonometry

I have this trig problem where it asks to find $ \sin(10^{\circ})$, given $\cos(40^{\circ})=a$.
 I tried the write the $\sin(10^{\circ})$ as $\sin(40^{\circ}-30^{\circ})$ to use the sum formula but i didn't get anywhere near to the options given in the test:

a)$\sin(10^{\circ})=2a$

b)$\sin(10^{\circ})=2a^2$

c)$\sin(10^{\circ})=2a-1$

d)$\sin(10^{\circ})=2a^2+1$

Comment: Are you sure that c) is not $2 a^2 - 1$?

Comment: Yes i double checked it. It's not the first time they made such mistakes so it comes as no surprise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have used here two facts $$\sin { \left( \alpha  \right) =\cos { \left( 90^{ \circ  }-\alpha  \right)  }  } \\ \cos { \left( 2\alpha  \right) =\cos ^{ 2 }{ \alpha -\sin ^{ 2 }{ \alpha  }  } =\cos ^{ 2 }{ \alpha -\left( 1-\cos ^{ 2 }{ \alpha  }  \right) =2\cos ^{ 2 }{ \alpha -1 }  }  } $$

> $$\sin { \left( 10^{ \circ  } \right) =\cos { \left( 80^{ \circ  } \right) =2\cos ^{ 2 }{ \left( 40^{ \circ  } \right)  } -1 } =2{ a }^{ 2 }-1 } $$

Comment: will you please explain the steps, it might seem easy but i really need to understand what is going on.

Comment: The formuae used are: $\cos(90-\theta)=\sin(\theta) $ and $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^{2}(\theta)-1$

Comment: So the right answer is missing from the four options, right?

Comment: Unfortunately yes

Comment: Would the identity of cos(2x) still apply to find sin(20) instead of sine(10)

Comment: Yes you can find by this way,but it will be a long way

Comment: So they made sure the given angles would work with identity?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right lines

\begin{align*}
\sin(10) &= \sin(40-30) \\ 
&= \sin(40)\cos(30)-\cos(40)\sin(30) \\ 
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(40) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(40) \\ 
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt{1-\cos^2(40)} - \frac{1}{2}\cos(40) \\ 
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sqrt{1-a^2} - \frac{1}{2}a \\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: The one by @haqnatural is much more elegant